# min value from a string contains number, character and space

Tags: javascript

Encountered a string, contains both number as well Character with space like

> ```
> " 7, 4, B, 9"
> ```

I am trying to get minimum value out of it.

By converting into an array and using Min function we can get the value out of it.

When we are having string and space with it, how to do it in one go.

Please suggest me

Comment: This one-liner : `(" 7, 4, B, 9".match(/\d+/g) || []).sort().shift()` will return the lowest value, or `undefined` if it does not find a number in that String.

Comment: Thank you Blex. It works fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let myStr = ' 7, 4, B, 9'
Math.min.apply( null, myStr.match(/\d+/g) )
```

First we create the array using `match` with a simple regex.  Then we apply the `Math.min` function to each element of the array.

Comment: Thank you Josh for your quick help

Answer (score 0):

I instead came up with this example if it happens to suit the needs:

```js
search = " 7, 4, B, 9";
min = 9999; search.split(",").forEach( function (val) {
    val = val.replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'');
    return Number(val) == val
        ? (min = min < val ? min : val) 
        : (String(val).charCodeAt(0) > min 
            ? min 
            : String(val).charCodeAt(0) )
} );
console.log(min)
```

It should work just fine in the browser console.

Comment: Nonspecific instructions.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function doTheThing(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function(item){
        return typeof item === "number";
    }).reduce(function(p, c) {
        return Math.min(p, c);
    });
}

document.write(doTheThing([5, 6, "A", 61, "B"]));
```